# How to use Js.Option.map?

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

For this code:

```js
  // val map : ('a -> 'b [@bs]) -> 'a option -> 'b option
  let optTest: Js.Option.t(int) = Js.Option.map(x => x, Js.Option.some(1));
```

I am getting following error:

```
  This expression should not be a function, the expected type is (. 'a) => 'b
```

where `x => x` is red. I am really confused, why the `map` isn't working? From its type signature it looks I am using it correctly, yet compiler says the first argument is not supposed to be a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer** - use [`Belt.Option.map`](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Belt.Option.html#VALmap) instead:

```rust
let optTest: option(int) = Belt.Option.map(Some(1), x => x);
```

**Long answer:**

The `Js` namespace is intended mostly for bindings to JavaScript's standard APIs. And while `Js.Option` for historical reasons was included in this namespace, the conventions used in the `Js` namespace is still that of very thin bindings.

The type you see for the callback function in the documentation, `'a -> 'b [@bs]`, and the type you see in the error message, `(. 'a) => 'b`, are exactly the same type. But the former is in OCaml's syntax while the latter is in Reason's, and also sugared up to look less offensive. Either way, the problem is that you're passing it an ordinary function when it expects this weird other kind of function.

The weird other kind of function is called an [uncurried](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/function#curry-uncurry) function. It's called that because "normal" functions in Reason are curried, while JavaScript functions are not. An uncurried function is therefore essentially just a native JavaScript function, which you sometimes need to deal with because you might receive one or need to pass one to a higher-order JavaScript function, like those in the `Js` namespace.

So how do you create an uncurried function in Reason? Just add a `.`, like in the type:

```rust
let optTest: option(int) = Js.Option.map((.x) => x, Some(1);
```

Or if you want to do it without the sugar (which you don't, but for the sake of completeness):

```rust
let optTest: option(int) = Js.Option.map([@bs] x => x, Some(1);
```

**Addendum:**

You might have noticed that I've replaced `Js.Option.t` and `Js.Option.some` in your example with `option` and `Some`. That's because those are the actual primitives. The `option` type is essentially defined as

```rust
type option('a) =
  | Some('a)
  | None
```

and is available everywhere.

`Js.Option.t('a)` (and `Belt.Option.t('a)`) is just an alias. And `Js.Option.some` is just a convenience function which doesn't have any equivalent in `Belt.Option`. They're mostly just there for consistency, and you should normally use the actual type and variant constructors instead.

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. I'm just learning reason and reading your explanation really helped me to understand it better. It's great when someone puts effort to help community.